# Determine if an entity is a certain content type

Tags: 8

I'm using drupal 8.

Lets assume the following. I have created a content type called `Foo`. Using the presave hook(`hook_entity_presave`), I'm modifying some fields in that content type.

Firstly I want to determine if the entity I'm modifying is a `Foo` content type.

I've tried using `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity->getEntityType()` however the return is `object(Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityType)`. So basically an object.

Since my knowledge of drupal 8 is not that great(yet) I assumed initially that it would return something more quantifiable like a string or something of the sort. Obviously I was wrong.

Secondly I want to NOT modify some fields if the fields already have a value. Again, I assume a simple `isset` or `empty` will do the trick. I could be wrong. If there are some other ways to do that, more drupal-like way, I'd be more than happy to understand it better.

Comment: For the second question this might help http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/219559/how-to-get-the-original-entity-on-hook-entity-presave. You can check in the original entity if a field is empty by using isEmpty(). Ask a question if it's unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to check the entity type and content type like this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function hook_entity_presave(EntityInterface $entity) {
  if($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'my_entity_type' && $entity->bundle() == 'my_content_type') {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```

Where `my_entity_type` is the entity type and `my_content_type` is the content type.

Adding Clive's answer, since the entity type you want to work with is already known to be a node, you can use `hook_node_presave()` instead of `hook_entity_presave`:

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

function hook_entity_presave(EntityInterface $node) {
  if($node->bundle() == 'my_content_type') {
    // Do your stuff here
  }
}
```